# Proper Method to Install Magento 2?

Tags: magento2

I have several questions about the 2 ways I can see of installing magento 2 and hopefully this will help me solve my confusion over this subject matter

My reference is http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/bk-install-guide.html

1. What are the pros/cons of installing via the command line instead of using a clone from github?
2. If I install via command line then does that mean that I can't use composer to update/install extensions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Install from github clone not make any problem.

2) Installed using command line then also you can use composer for update/install extensions